# What does [rm -rf /] do?

Tags: command-line, rm

This is basically recursively remove everything from root right?

Would this really delete everything on the device?

Do any operating systems have protections against running this – like a confirmation or something?

Seemed like a better idea to ask than to try.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/604324/how-is-rm-rf-able-to-delete-all-files-in-the-system that command would require `--no-preserve-root`

Comment: answers have not yet covered some point about "Would this really delete everything on the device?": even with all the necessary access rights (root/sudo), a file that is currently used is not necessarily deleted with rm directly. However, it will be as soon at it is closed. So, your system will not be completely and utterly destroyed _right after_ the command, but as soon as you (try to) reboot, for instance, things will get deleted. The kernel will probably panic at some point, meaning that you may have remaining files after this process (but a probably useless state of your file system)

Comment: "Seemed like a better idea to ask than to try." indeed, however you can easily setup an isolated virtual machine and try it in here. (be careful not to mount any local disk folder, or some other kind of folder link,  though!)

Answer (score 1):

The rm command means it is applied for removing file-folders based on the file path but as you have specified `rm -rf /` it tells to remove the files which are part of the root directory in the Linux or Unix based system, but again it will not do anything until and unless you apply the command with `sudo` access or super user do access with your system password.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this would delete recursively.

Actually their is also a protection:

`rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on '/'
rm: use --no-preserve-root to override this failsafe`

Answer (score 0):

rm -rf is a dangerouse command in linux.if rm -rf run with root privilage it force to delete all files and folders even hidden file and you must install os again. this command has not confirmation question.
As a security measure, you can set rm to always get you approved for the delete operation, it uses the "-i" option whenever you want to delete a file or directory. To make this command permanent, add the following alias to the $ HOME / .bashrc file.
When you run the rm command, it will run with the "-i" option by default. (If you use the "-f" option, these settings will be overwrite)

Comment: "this command has not confirmation question" it actually has one (see other answer). Maybe more info on the version / variant you use would make the answer more accurate more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf
```

this code deletes all files on linux (system ,root files include)
this is very dangerous code